# Matching regular expressions (python)

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

For a sequence like:

NM_001003443 chr11 + 5925152 5926098 5925152 5926098 2 5925152,5925652, 5925404,5926098,

I want an information line that looks like the following (unspliced, meaning there is a '-s' in sys.argv):

`>NM_00100343|chr11(+):5925152Z5926098`

or (spliced, no '-s' in sys.argv):

`>NM_00100343|chr11(+):5925152Z5926098|5925151Z5925404,5925652Z5926098`

I have attempted to do this, yet keep getting incorrect matches, could someone look at my regular expression and see if it looks and/or is matching correctly?

I have written:

p = '(NM_\d+)\s+(chr\d+)\s+([+|-])\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+),(\d+),\s+(\d+),(\d+),'

and have tried to match them by (each line in the file looks like the line example given above, opened by fp = open(infile, 'r'):

```
for line in fp:
    r = search(p, line)
    if '-s' in sys.argv and r:
        wp.write('>'+r.group(1)+'|'+r.group(2)+'('+r.group(3)+')'+':'+r.group(4)+'-'+r.group(5))
    else:
        wp.write('>'+r.group(1)+'|'+r.group(2)+'('+r.group(3)+')'+':'+r.group(4)+'-'+r.group(5)+'|'+r.group(6)+'-'+r.group(11)+','+r.group(9)+'-'+r.group(12))
```

**Edit, does this appear to be correct?**

```
for line in fp:
    line = line.replace(',',' ')
    tokens = line.split()
    if '-s' in sys.argv and r:
        wp.write('>'+tokens[0]+'|'+tokens[1]+'('+tokens[2]+')'+':'+tokens[3]+'-'+tokens[4])
    else:
        wp.write('>'+tokens[0]+'|'+tokens[1]+'('+tokens[2]+')'+':'+tokens[3]+'-'+tokens[4]+'|'+tokens[5]+'-'+tokens[10]+','+tokens[8]+'-'+tokens[11])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the data you need is separated by white space or a comma, so you don't need a regex at all.

```
mystring = mystring.replace(',', ' ')  # convert all commas to spaces
tokens = mystring.split()  # split at spaces
```

If want insist an a regex, there are a few typos. This is the correct regext:
`p = '(NM_\d+)\s+(chr\d+)\s+([+|-])\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+),(\d+),\s+(\d+),(\d+),'`

1. `[+-]` without parens and |
2. missing `\s+` after `(chr\d+)`
3. missing `\` in the term `,s+(` towards the end of the regexp

Comment: If I split at the spaces, how do I make it look like the desired format?

Comment: @CodeChordsman - it should be `[+-]` rather than `[+|-]` as it's a character class

Comment: I have edited my code, does this appear to be correct formatting since I am reading lines in a file??